# same expression different answer

Tags: c

with commenting the first //printf() I got the answer 0.000000 while without commenting the first printf() i got 5.000000 and 5.000000 ??

```c
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    float d;
    d=2+2*3/2;
    printf("%f\n",d);//5.000000
    printf("%f",2+2*3/2);//5.000000
    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    float d;
    d=2+2*3/2;
    //printf("%f\n",d);
    printf("%f",2+2*3/2);//0.000000
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think `2+2*3/2` doesn't evaluate to a `float`, so what you get is kind of undefined. You should force it to evaluate to a float by changeing to something like `2+2*3.0/2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760369/c-programming-printf-format-searches-expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer explained, when you try to print an `int` value using `%f`, the behavior is undefined, so anything can happen.

In a comment on that other answer, you suggested "if I'm lying to `printf` then in both examples it should be same", and I replied with another comment about the unpredictability of car crashes.

But now I'm going to try to answer your question, but there's a catch: you're going to have to sit through another little lecture first.

When you hear that something is formally undefined (this applies to any system, not just C programming), there's really only one sane course of action, namely: *don't do that thing*.  Avoid it like the plague.  It's poison, it's evil.  It might seem to do something reasonable for a little while, but only long enough to tantalize you or get you dependent on it, and then it'll shift, leaving you derelict.

It's also not a good idea to ask why the thing is undefined, or what the expected range of behaviors might be, or why you saw one behavior one time and a different behavior another time.  In general, none of these questions is answerable.  Also, even if an answer is offered, some programmers (not you, I know, but some people) try to use the answer to justify retaining a piece of code containing undefined behavior that they think they can predict the behavior of.  This exercise is perilous.

As compilers get more sophisticated, and as optimizations get more aggressive, the kinds of things that happen when your code contains undefined behavior get stranger and stranger.  You really can't predict it, you really do have to avoid it.

But: what about your program?  Why did the broken call

```
printf("%f\n", 2+2*3/2);
```

print 0 when called in isolation, but 5 (seemingly the correct answer) when preceded by a different call which also printed 5?

To answer this, we need to know how values get passed to functions, and this varies from machine to machine, which is one of the factors that makes questions like this difficult-to-impossible to answer.

On a lot of machines, the first few values of type `int` get passed to functions in two or three registers which are reserved for integers, and the first few values of type `double` get passed in two or three registers which are reserved for doubles.  (I know your program used a variable of type `float`, but when calling `printf`, floats always get promoted to double.)

So this makes it pretty easy to see why, on such a machine, a call like

```
printf("%f\n", 2+2*3/2);
```

doesn't work.  The expression `2+2*3/2` has type `int`, so its value gets placed into the first of those registers reserved for integers.  But when `printf` finds `%f` in the format string, it says to itself "`%f` is for doubles, so my caller should have passed a double, so I'll grab a value from the first register reserved for doubles."  But nothing got placed in the first register reserved for doubles, so the value printed is whatever happened to be there already, which might just be 0.

*But* (and you can probably see where this is going), *if* there was a preceding call which printed a floating-point 5 properly, then the value 5.0 got placed into that first register reserved for doubles, so when you wrongly call

```
printf("%f\n", 2+2*3/2);
```

this time, `printf` goes to that register and finds 5, and prints it.

To test this hypothesis, I just tried an experiment.  I had already determined that my machine behaved the same way yours did on your two programs, printing 5 and 5 for the first program but 0 for the second.  (This was kind of a surprise, actually -- since undefined behavior means anything can happen, it's even more likely to do something different on different machines under different operating systems and different compilers.)  So I tried this code:

```
printf("%f\n", 7.7);
printf("%f\n", 2+2*3/2);
```

See if you can guess what it printed.  (And, since it seems our machines are similar, you can probably try it and get the same result on your machine, too.)

Comment: I got it so the second printf will also print the same value 7.7 because again its wrongly call and from the previous printf 7.7 in the register thanks for making that easier.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Your code (*both* cases) is invoking undefined behavior by sending an `int` to a function expecting a `double`.

---

Your code invokes *undefined behavior*.  This:

```
2+2*3/2
```

is an `int` expression. While it is acceptable to assign this to a `float` as you did to `d` in the first example, and allow automatic conversion to take place (buyer beware; know what you're doing), it is *not* acceptable to send an `int` to a variadic (or otherwise) function requiring something different.

This:

```
printf("%f\n",d);
```

is implicitly promoting `d` to a `double` value per the rules of variadic functions in the C langauge. Within `printf`, the `%f` format specifier is used to determine there should be a `double` in the variadic argument list, and sure enough there is. Note: the promotion to `double` has *nothing* to with `%f`. The latter expects a `double`, but the variadic nature of `printf` is what instigates the `float` to `double` promotion.

This, on the other hand:

```
printf("%f",2+2*3/2);
```

is sending an `int` to `printf`, which in turn is *still* expecting a `double`, but no longer receiving one. Basically, you're lying to `printf`, and the result is a spin of the whacky wheel of mayhem.

Comment: so why it's not printing 0.0 in first code. printf("%f",2+2*3/2);//5.000000

Comment: @KshitizDeep That line invokes *undefined behavior*. I could go into the *potential* internals of what is actually happening in your implementation interpretation of *invalid* arguments to the function, but in the end, it doesn't matter. The call itself is invalid. Seeking definitive behavior analysis where there is no definition of behavior is ultimately a straw endeavor.

Comment: why "printf("%f",2+2*3/2)" expression give two different results if i'm lying to printf then in both the example it should be same how at one plce 5, other place 0 come

Comment: @PushpamKumar thus the very nature of *undefined behavior*. The call is invalid.

Comment: Expecting consistent behavior when dabbling in undefined behavior, asking why you got one result one time and a different result another time, is kind of like asking: "I took the front wheel off my car to work on the brakes.  I put the wheel back on, but I forgot to fasten the lug nuts.  I went for a drive, and at 60mph, the front wheel flew off, and I crashed into a ditch.  I wiped the blood off my forehead, found the wheel, put it back on, and forgot to fasten the lug nuts again.  This time, when I resumed driving, the wheel flew off and I crashed head-on into a semi.  Why the difference?"