# How does printf function work in the following case?

Tags: c

Why does this program prints 0.000000? Not only for given value of x, it prints zero for any integer value of x.

According to my understanding, if printf fetches the integer as a float value, then the result should not be zero.

```
void main()
{
    int x = 1084926634;
    printf("%f",x);
}
```

Expected result : Other than zero (5.xxxx according to my calculation)
Actual result : 0.000000

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct tag? Did you mean C++?

Comment: It is C. Not C++.

Comment: You should post this with the C tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c - you're currently  on the C# tag.

Comment: It doesn't. You're causing undefined behaviour by mismatching the format tag with the actual type of the variable.

Comment: Pavankumar S V, `printf("%f"` expects a `double`, why use `int`?

Comment: UB, and `void main` is wrong.

Comment: *Expected result: 5.xxxx according to my calculation.* Are you expecting a 32-bit `int` to be treated as a 32-bit `float`? Well, if you pass a `float` argument to `printf` it will be promoted to a `double` which is what `%f` expects. But you didn't do that, you passed `int` which remains as 32 bits.

Comment: See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57243776/same-expression-different-answer) for some insight.

Comment: All bets are really off. Either you're using a 32-bit system and the stack below the arguments were conveniently 0 or 64-bit system and it is because the floating point register used for register passing was empty. The former is unlikely though in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the C standard this conversion is undefined so the compiler can realistic output what it wants.
`If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.`

See the following for more info:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf